# SQL query with averages pr. year

Tags: sql

I have a table with meetings containing the date of the meeting.

I have another table with persons.

I have a third table with meeting participations, i.e. if a person participated in a meeting, there will be a record containing the person's ID in the "person" column and the meeting's ID in the "meeting" column.

Now, I need a list of how many persons participated in meetings on average, per year. E.g. "In 2011, there were an average of 21.6 persons pr. meeting".

I feel I should be able to do this in SQL, but I have no idea how...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many of the products aren't ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the average number of participants per meeting by dividing the total number of participants by the number of meetings.

A `group by` accomplishes this:

```
select year(m.meetingdate) as yyyy, count(*) / count(distinct m.meetingid)
from meetings m join
     participants p
     on m.meetingid = p.meetingid
group by year(m.meetingdate)
order by year(m.meetingdate);
```

Note:  some databases have other ways to express `year()`.  Some databases do integer division, so you would want to convert the values to decimal or float before the division.

Comment: LEFT JOIN, if there's a meeting without any participants?

Comment: Since ANSI SQL allows nothing but columns in the GROUP BY clause, I'd go with a derived table here.

Comment: Amazing - just what I needed - thank you very, very much! Worked right out of the box :-) How does one learn to think in SQL? ;-)

Comment: @OZ1SEJ . . . Practice.